# Converting /scan data for Lidar that is not centered on Robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Lidar is not centered over the Robot/ Generally for SLAM and AMCL I think that's ok because if you have the tfs set up correctly then Slam and AMCL will take it into account.

However, I am using /scan messages which give me, let’s say, 360 numbers, corresponding to the distance of an obstacle from the lidar. To know the distance from the robot, I need to do a little converting, involving some trigonometry, using information that I get from tf.

This must be a solved problem. Can someone give me a pointer perhaps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405344/converting-/scan-data-for-lidar-that-is-not-centered-on-robot/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2022-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-23**:
I suggest subscribing to the /scan topic and then converting those polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. Once you have Cartesian coordinates as XYZ values, you can transform those points simply by one matrix multiplication.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2022-08-23**:
Yeah that sounds like the way to go. Thanks. If you make this into an answer I will mark it good!!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-23**:
@pitosalas  Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest subscribing to the /scan topic and then converting those polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.

Once you have Cartesian coordinates as XYZ values, you can transform these points simply by one matrix multiplication.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2